# How to hide config value in Deploy to Heroku form via app.json

Tags: heroku, passwords, password-protection

When using [`app.json`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema) to define the configuration variables for the [Deploy to Heroku button](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button) form, is there a way to have the form present a password field so the value isn't visible in the HTML page? This would be like having a HTML input element with the type attribute set to `password`.

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema